# reloading .mo files for all processes/threads in django without a restart

Tags: python, django

We are working on a .po file editor for translators. And the translators need to see the changes they are doing on the live website.

We managed to reload the .mo files for the current process/thread. but not for every process/thread.

Is there a possibility to accomplish this without bigger performance problems?

Comment: how did you reload them for the current thread?

Answer (score 6):

We had the same problem. Users must write translations direct on website. I've found middleware for django 1.1, that clear translation cache and try to use it in view with django 1.4.
order:

1. user submit from with translation
2. methods parse form data and change *.po
3. -subrocess.Popen(["python", "manage.py", "compilemessages"], stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE) (to compile changed *.po)
4. function  below to clear cache

   ```
   from django.utils import translation
   from django.utils.translation import trans_real, get_language
   from django.conf import settings
   import gettext

   if settings.USE_I18N:

       try:

           # Reset gettext.GNUTranslation cache.
           gettext._translations = {}

           # Reset Django by-language translation cache.
          trans_real._translations = {}

       # Delete Django current language translation cache.
       trans_real._default = None

       # Delete translation cache for the current thread,
       # and re-activate the currently selected language (if any)
       translation.activate(get_language())
   except AttributeError:
       pass
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I checked [django-rosetta](http://code.google.com/p/django-rosetta/) and, as I suspected, they rely on the [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) AutoReload mechanism.  This is what I would have suggested.  For more details read [Reloading Source Code](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode).

Comment: From memory the django-rosetta touches the WSGI script file when committing a change to the definition files.